# org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: error executing work &

Tags: java, xml, hibernate

**This is my MyWork class**

```
public class MyWork implements Work
 {
    @Override
    public void execute(Connection con) throws SQLException 
    {
        CallableStatement cstmt=con.prepareCall("{?=call emp_bonus(?)}");
        cstmt.registerOutParameter(1, Types.DOUBLE);
        Scanner s= new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("enter employee number");
        int eno=s.nextInt();
        cstmt.setInt(2, eno);
        cstmt.execute();
        Double bonus=cstmt.getDouble(1);
        System.out.println("Bonus="+bonus);
        cstmt.close();
    }
}
```

**This is my Test class**

package com.sathya.test;

```
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;

import com.sathya.util.HibernateUtil;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        SessionFactory factory=HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
        Session session=factory.openSession();
        session.doWork(new MyWork());
        session.close();
    }

}
```

**

> 

i'm getting error

## org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: error executing work

---

**

Comment: I'm afraid this is a great example of: **Why is my code not working?**

Answer (score 1):

Can you check if this is correct:

```
 CallableStatement cstmt=con.prepareCall("{?=call emp_bonus(?)}");
```

Number of parameter passed matches the database procedure.